# use grep to return a list of files, given multiple keywords (like google returns a list of webpages)

Tags: grep, keyword

I need to find ALL files that have multiple keywords anywhere in the file (not necessarily on the same line), given a starting directory like ~/. Does "grep -ro" do this?

(I'm using Unix, Mac OSX 10.4)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-l` option to get a list of filenames with matches, so it's just a matter of finding all of the files that have the first keyword and then filtering that list down to the files that also have the second keyword:

```
grep -rl first_keyword basedir | xargs grep -l second_keyword
```

Answer (score 0):

To search just *.txt

```
find ~/. -name "*.txt" | xargs grep -l first_keyword | xargs grep -l second_keyword
```

Thanks Adam!

Comment: note that "find" doesn't work for paths containing spaces like "my path/"

Comment: (or for filenames containing spaces like "my file name.txt")